# WordPress - Issue when displaying posts using a custom select query

Tags: wordpress

I need to display some posts using a custom select query. This custom select query needs to get the posts in two taxonomies.

Look the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID =
$wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy
ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =
$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id =
$wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE
$wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'continentes'
AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'asia'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'pais'
AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'china'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
```

If a just use one condition the query works well, like it:

...
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'continentes'
AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'asia'
...

But I need the posts in taxonomy "continentes" and "pais".

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
...
AND 
($wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'continentes' 
OR 
$wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'pais')
...
```

If Wordpress supports it you can use `IN`:

```
...
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy in ('continentes', 'pais')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each post only has 1 taxonomy, your query won't return any results, as a post can't be in both continents and pais. you need to change your where clause to look like this:

```
AND ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'continentes' OR $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'pais')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to the reply!

The post has these two taxonomies. "continents" and "pais".